# Codeigniter HMVC + Rest_Controller with Dynamic Module Path

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I am working on creating an application with having an HMVC structure in codeigniter and i also require API Centric application , so i used https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc for HMVC and Rest_Controller of [Phil Sturgeon](https://github.com/philsturgeon), now everything is working fine , but the problem is for each controller in the module i have to add the static path

```
require APPPATH.'modules/modulename/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
```

i want to make this path dynamic , or auto load libraries for each module in the module's library folder, adding library name in the module/config/autoload.php is not working for me , as i think the reason is the code flow of application, first the application flow goes to the controller and it gets to my class extending the REST_Controller and gives the error , unable to load the REST_Controller Class

Note: if i put the Rest_Controller.php and Format.php in the application/libraries/ folder, everything works fine , but i want this to be modular , and make the module restful

how can i load libraries specifically from the module/libraries
how to make it proper modular, so that there should be a complete instance of codeigniter in the module ,it should work freely, including the files loaded from the main application.

**My folder structure is as follows**

> application
>   - - modules
>   - - - - modulename
>   - - - - - - controller
>   - - - - - - libraries
>   - - - - - - config
>   - - - - - - models
>   - - - - - - views

My Rest_Controller Class in the application/modules/module_name/libraries/Rest_Controller.php

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends MX_Controller
```

My Controller Class in application/modules/module_name/controllers/User.php

```
require APPPATH.'modules/modulename/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class User extends REST_Controller
{
```

this works fine but if i remove the require line from the top , it doesn't work and even if i add the library name to autoload.php in the /modulename/config/autoload.php

it doesn't work
 My autoload.php /application/modules/modulename/config/autoload.php

```
<?phpif ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','modulename/REST_Controller');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

and autoload.php in my application/config/autoload.php is empty, means no autoload mentioned

Comment: try use `autoload` in config.php or load in custom `MY_Controller` extended class

Comment: Bora , by autoload you mean $autoload and can you please more elaborate what you want me to try, i am new to codeigniter, thanks

Comment: Something like that `$autoload['libraries'] = array('api/REST_Controller');` in `application/config/autoload.php`. HMVC extension should work properly.

Comment: on the main appliation level , i don't want to do that, i want the library to be loaded on the module level, and i have tried doing it in     application/modules/modulename/config/autoload.php  and it didn't worked

Comment: If you want to load module level, api doesnt work while running another module. Module autoload run only user on api module. Could you share us your `autoload.php`?

Comment: yeah, i want it to load only for this module, or if i place it on other module2/libraries , then it should be loaded for module2. what i wanna get is that every module should be able to load it's libraries from it's specific libraries folder. I tried putting `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','modulename/rest_controller'); ` didn't worked, getting **error <br> Fatal error: Class 'REST_Controller' not found in /application/modules/modulename/controllers/User.php**

Comment: Are you sure that HMVC extension works properly? Module locations etc.. Try main autoload `$autoload['libraries'] = array('modulename/REST_Controller');` in `application/config/autoload.php` for test working or not.

Comment: tried that, putting mentioned in the main autoload.php in application/config/autoload.php , still not working, same error and also the modular thing is working , as the error mentions that it's reaching to the controller file with the modular api but not able to get the rest_controller class which is in the libraries folder of the module

Comment: Even though you write in there and does not work, there is a problem about HMVC. There are high chances it will work when you move `REST_Controller.php` to `application/libraries` and autoload without prefix `modulename`

Comment: yeah, that way it works , and that's i don't want , because it will then load for the complete application, not for the module , and this way the modularity of the application is disturbed

Comment: Check out again HMVC files and configuration..

Comment: don't know what to check , because hmvc is working fine, controllers are working, urls are fine , it's taking views from proper folder and also controllers can be loaded into other controller

Comment: Hmm.. Did you try running the constructor like that? `class User extends REST_Controller{ $autoload = array('libraries' => array('modulename/REST_Controller')); }`

Comment: yeah, i have tried, but the logic is that when we are writing `class User extends REST_Controller{` the same time it looks for the rest_controller to extend and compiler is not able to find the class it gives error , and the autload line is executed after the declaration of class

Comment: somehow the CI should load the configurations and the libraries before the instantiation of the constructor classes , but i think so CI is first loading the constructor class that's y it start looking for the REST_Controller class to extend and unable to find that, i also tried to echo something in the /application/modules/modulename/config/autoload.php , it doesn't echo anything before the class instantiation , and echoes afterwards

Answer (score 0):

First - it isn't clear but your structure should look like this:

```
application
- - modules
- - - - modulename
- - - - - - controller
- - - - - - - modulename.php
- - - - - - libraries
- - - - - - - Rest_Conctroller.php
- - - - - - config
- - - - - - - autoload.php
- - - - - - models
- - - - - - views
```

Then use

```
$this->load->library('rest_controller');
```

Within your `modulename.php` controller to check it works first of all and you have all the paths defined correctly.

If it works then comment that line out first of all.

Then within your `autoload.php` file in your `modulename/config` folder just set:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('rest_controller');
```

Then try it again - notice there is nothing before the class name.

This will definitely work as I have tried it - if it doesn't it seems you have either modified your routes incorrectly or have been playing with files elsewhere (maybe over-ridden something in a custom controller?)

Comment: As a side-note when testing things like this create a file called 'working.php' with class 'Working' -> then in `__construct` just echo "I am working" -> it is an easier way to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have the same structure as you have mentioned above and it doesn't work, i have tried both ways told by you, doesn't work, and i have no routes defined, the routes.php is empty, and i have other problems also, like if i put subdirectories in views directory of module it don't load view from the subdir only from the main directory, i was using CI version 2.2., i have downloaded 2.1.4, but still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry but without actually debugging your code directly I don't think I can help then. I have used it for quite some time without a hitch - sounds like you are either trying to auto-load a module twice, which we cause it to fail, or that you have something wrong in your config file. Also check your .htaccess file - Did you try the 'working.php' file way of doing things - it does at least rule out your rest controller being the cause.

Comment: i have a MY_Controller which extends MX_Controllers can i just extend MY_Controller to REST_Controller?